# Monitoring search terms in Plone

Tags: search, plone

I'd like to get a better idea of what people are searching for when they're using our website.

Just curious, what's the best way to monitor what's being entered into the search field in Plone 4? I saw this product — http://plone.org/products/ifsearchmonitor — but it's an old one. Has anyone used it with Plone 4 or know of something similar?

Answer (score 8):

Okay I don't know why it took me so long to realize this, but it's built into Google Analytics. Here are instructions: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012264?hl=en

And the search query parameters I used for Plone are: @@search, SearchableText, advanced_search

Answer (score 1):

using google analytic's site search won't track users using the livesearch (without pressing enter and submit to the @@search view.

for awstats i use this extra section to track both:

```
# updated version for plone 4.3
# /livesearch_reply?q=testsuche
# /@@search?SearchableText=testsuche
# /@@updated_search?SearchableText=testsuche
# livesearches shown as q=, normal searches with just the phrase
ExtraSectionName1="Plone Suchabfragen"
ExtraSectionCodeFilter1="200 304"
ExtraSectionCondition1="URL,\/@@search||URL,\/search||URL,\/@@updated_search||URL,\/livesearch_reply"
ExtraSectionFirstColumnTitle1="Search:"
#ExtraSectionFirstColumnValues1="QUERY_STRING,SearchableText=([^&]+)||QUERY_STRING,q=([^&]+)"
ExtraSectionFirstColumnValues1="QUERY_STRING,SearchableText=([^&]+)||QUERY_STRING,(q=[^&]+)"
ExtraSectionFirstColumnFormat1="%s"
ExtraSectionStatTypes1=PL
ExtraSectionAddAverageRow1=0
ExtraSectionAddSumRow1=1
MaxNbOfExtra1=100
MinHitExtra1=1
```

if you want to track the livesearch in google analytics, you'll need to use event tracking: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events